# be redirected to users/sign_in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

I have a controller of Workers.

If I logged out, I am redirected to: `localhost:3000`. I want to be redirect to the sign_in of my devise.

this is my `rake routes`:

```
users_sign_out           GET    /users/sign_out(.:format)       devise/sessions#destroy
new_user_session         GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)        devise/sessions#new
user_session             POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)        devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session     DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)       devise/sessions#destroy
user_password            POST   /users/password(.:format)       devise/passwords#create
new_user_password        GET    /users/password/new(.:format)   devise/passwords#new
edit_user_password       GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)  devise/passwords#edit
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)       devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)         devise/registrations#cancel
user_registration        POST   /users(.:format)                devise/registrations#create
new_user_registration    GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)        devise/registrations#new
edit_user_registration   GET    /users/edit(.:format)           devise/registrations#edit
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                devise/registrations#destroy
```

and this is my `routes.rb`:

```
devise_for :users do get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy' end
resources :tasksadmins
resources :workers
root to: "devise/registrations#create"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is specified in the devise wiki.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-redirect-path-after-destroying-a-session-i.e.-signing-out

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  private

  # Overwriting the sign_out redirect path method
  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    new_user_session_path
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In you can override the [after_sign_out_path_for](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Controllers/Helpers#after_sign_out_path_for-instance_method) helper in your application controller.

```
def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  # logic here
end
```